# Firedac - Datasnap + FDMemtable + fkInternalCalc

Tags: delphi, firedac

Estou enfrentando problemas com campos `fkInternalCalc` ao migrar de `TClientDataSet` para `TFDMemtable`.

Utilizamos esses campos para manipulação de dados em memória, mas eles, não serão persistidos, isso é muito útil.

Temos uma aplicação`datasnap`e criamos um método genérico para recuperar do server um`TFDJSONDataSets`.

```
procedure TProxyExec.Open(const DataSet: TFDMemTable; Query: String;
const TipoSever: TipoServerDB);
var
   Dados: TFDJSONDataSets;
begin
   try
      GetDataSet(Query,Dados,TipoSever);
      DataSet.Close;
      DataSet.AppendData(TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListValue(Dados,0));
   finally
      FreeAndNil(Dados);
   end;
end;
```

Tudo ocorre como esperado quando o`DataSet`passado como parâmetro não tem em seus`Fields`, um que esteja configurado como`fkInternalCalc`.

Mas quando isso acontece, ou seja, quando existe um field`fkInternalCalc` previamente criado no `FDMemtable`, ao executar a linha

```
DataSet.AppendData(TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListValue(Dados,0));
```

o erro abaixo acontece; [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> ```
> Debugger Exception Notification Programa.exe raised exception class
> FDException with message [FireDAC] [DatS]-38. Cannot change table
> [fdmTabela] structure, when table has rows'.
> ```

Fiz debug utilizando os`.dcus`, não cheguei em um consenso. Alguém já passou por isso?

Estamos usando XE7 - Update1 Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Boa, descobri! 
Aparentemente, quando existem campos do tipo **fkInternalCalc** você precisa abrir o Dataset, dar um DataSet.Open() antes do DataSet.AppendData, com isso de alguma forma os campos são preparados e AppendData funciona corretamente. Meu código genérico final ficou assim;

```
procedure TProxyExec.Open(const DataSet: TFDMemTable; Query: String;
const TipoSever: TipoServerDB);
var
   Dados: TFDJSONDataSets;
begin
   try
      GetDataSet(Query,Dados,TipoSever);
      DataSet.Close;
      DataSet.Open() <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      DataSet.AppendData(TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListValue(Dados,0));
   finally
      FreeAndNil(Dados);
   end;
end;
```